# How to get console.log from Xbox UWP app?

Tags: logging, uwp, xbox

I've Xbox UWP app, there is some intermittent issue and I would like to capture the logs to analyze.

However I am not sure how I can collect logs from Xbox for my analysis.

If anybody has any info, please let me know.

Comment: You could try to use [App Center](https://appcenter.ms/) in your app.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT any other way? I have developer account with https://partner.microsoft.com/ and just upload my package under Windows&Xbox

Comment: If you don't want to use App Center, you could try some other third-party libraries that could save logs in your app.